# how to upload file to sharepoint doc library via c# application?

Tags: development, web-services, file-upload

I need to upload files with specific information(custom fields) into sharepoint document library via custom windows application.

I have no idea how to do it, anyone has any examples how to do it either via web service or other methods?

[update]

Problem #2: During design time, i can add `MS.sharepoint.dll` without a problem, however when during compilation, it shows:

```
The type or namespace name 'SPWeb' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I'm pretty sure I added the dll and there's no error, only after compile it shows error.

Comment: There are various solutions to do so
1) Server Object Model
2) Client Object Model
are you going to run this Windows Application in a Client Machine where SharePoint is not installed?

Comment: Lets assumed it's not installed, which method do i use ? or how do i install it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link, http://www.ktskumar.com/blog/2009/03/upload-document-from-local-machine-to-sharepoint-library/

This blog post explains how to upload the document to SharePoint using WebService

Comment: how do i know i have this or not ? copyService.Url = webUrl+”/_vti_bin/copy.asmx”;

Comment: To check the URL, you have to browse through, http://<SiteUrl>/_vti_bin/copy.asmx . copyservice refers the WebService Reference. webUrl refers the website url

Comment: a) Link to your own blog but say it's your own blog. b) Please post the gist of your post and not just the link, some day this link might be broken.

Answer (score 5):

You can use an HTTP PUT request to put document in the library. The code may be (adapt regarding your needs) :

```
Uri destUri = new Uri("http://server/sites/mysite/myweb/mylibrary/document.doc");
using(FileStream inStream = File.OpenRead(@"c:\doc\document.doc"))
{
    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(destUri);
    req.Method = "PUT";
    req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; // assuming windows Auth
    using(Stream outStream = req.GetRequestStream())
    {
        CopyStream(inStream, outStream);
    }
}
```

The main advantage of this method is that you don't have any sharepoint code. This is standard http webdav behavior.

The major drawback is that you don't have set any metadata.

To fix the later issue, you can use the standard web services of SharePoint.

Comment: in that case, i will have to use standard web services of SP .. do i need to install anything on client ?

Comment: No. Simply add a service reference to the SharePoint web services in your VS project (lists.asmx or ListData.svc)

Comment: how do i get or how do i know they are activated? the address to upload is http://sharepoint/sites/company/ProcessControl/Packing%20%20Shipping/Forms/AllItems.aspx   internal server btw.

Comment: nvm, i got it.. just paste this instead of the aspx.. _vti_bin/copy.asmx

Comment: Eventhough there is no way of setting the metadata, I like this solution best because it also enables uploading files to Documentsets and SharePoint Folders.

Answer (score 3):

you can also use a Client Object Model Solution as Below

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://contoso.com/subsite"))
{
    try
    {
        List documentLibrary = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("List Title");
        FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
        newFile.Content = "Add File Stream Array";
        newFile.Overwrite = true;
        newFile.Url = "http://contoso.com/subsite/listurl/" + strFileName.Trim();
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = documentLibrary.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
    uploadFile.ListItemAllFields["Column Internal Name"] = "Column Internal Value";

        uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.Update();
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

And regarding your Problem No 2: Please make sure that you have opened up the **Visual Studio 2010 as Administrator**. Also change your project settings such that it is compiled with **.Net Framework 3.5 not with Framework 4.0**

Answer (score 1):

I would use Object model as shown in the following code sample:

```
String fileToUpload = @"C:\YourFile.txt";
String sharePointSite = "http://yoursite.com/sites/Research/";
String documentLibraryName = "Shared Documents";

using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(sharePointSite))
{
    using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
    {
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fileToUpload))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found.", fileToUpload);                    

        SPFolder myLibrary = oWeb.Folders[documentLibraryName];

        // Prepare to upload
        Boolean replaceExistingFiles = true;
        String fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileToUpload);
        FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileToUpload);

        // Upload document
        SPFile spfile = myLibrary.Files.Add(fileName, fileStream, replaceExistingFiles);

        // Commit 
        myLibrary.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: problem no 2: during design time, i can add MS.sharepoint.dll without a problem, however when during compilation, it shows, The type or namespace name 'SPWeb' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) .. im pretty sure I added  the dll and there's no error, only after compile it shows error.

Comment: Can you ask another question for that or you should had already mentioned it in your question or edit your existing question

Comment: i have edited my question

Answer (score -2):

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/programmatically-adding-document-to-sharepoint-document-library/

Comment: i do not see the windows sharpoint services under references, im  using vs2010

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.