# File upload control on a custom page in a WSS 3.0 site

Tags: wss-3.0, file-upload

I am designing a custom page(inheriting from a custom master page) in one of my WSS 3.0 website. I am displaying all the files in a document library in a data-view web part.

Now, on the same page we need to provide provision to user for uploading files to this document library. There are few custom columns also in the document library for which we expect user to input values while uploading any file. 
Can anybody suggest the best approach for this requirement ?

> We are looking for a code less (out of the box) solution for the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with wss-3.0, but I guess you can't just point `OpenPopupPage` to `/_layouts/Upload.aspx?List=...`? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar question: [how to upload file to sharepoint doc library via c# application?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45261/how-to-upload-file-to-sharepoint-doc-library-via-c-application)

Look at this article in msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms454491.aspx which states how to store file in sharepoint.

Basically, its similar to how you do in asp.net but with some provision related to content types/column values etc. You can handle it easily.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks Prashant. Actually we are looking for some out of the box solution(No server-side code) for this. I have edited my question accordingly. Do you have any suggestion for this ?

Comment: Yes for out of the box facility, you can open your page in sharepoint designer and add DataViewer web part.

Comment: DataViewer webpart will display the list items. But how would we get the option for File upload ?

Comment: It will also display option to add document, you can configure it so that it doesn't show any item (set filter in that way) and also configure it to not show headers