# Automate Browser Screenshot and insert image in SP library

Tags: 2010

My requirement is a SP browser screenshot has to be taken automatically and image should save in document library automatically.I did automate the procedure & saved image to C path , but its not saving in document library.They want to run this C# .net code in SSIS at DB level,so They ain't using power shell path, can this be happen ?

Any other work around to make this happen? (I'm new to Sharepoint and coding.)

Here C# code is opening the browser taking the screenshot and saving it in C path. Need extra code to save it in Document Library.

Answer (score 1):

You can just map the document library as a network share on the server and they save to that instead in the root.

Otherwise it takes more work to upload a file with code.  Review some of the other SE answers below for more information:

[how to upload file to sharepoint doc library via c# application?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45261/how-to-upload-file-to-sharepoint-doc-library-via-c-application)

Comment: Thank you I'll definitely do that and let you know the result.