# Upload documents from other websites

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, rest

I want to upload documents from a ASP MVC website to my Sharepoint document library. Found a lot of websites about this topic, but most of them are focussed on uploading documents from within Sharepoint.

I found [this article](http://geekswithblogs.net/ThorvaldBoe/archive/2014/06/06/how-to-upload-files-to-a-sharepoint-2013-document-library.aspx) about uploading documents with REST, but in the source code there are references to:

> _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl

Am I missing some libraries or is there another way to upload documents from outside Sharepoint?

Comment: Do you want to upload from server-side ASP MVC, or from client-side? From server side, could be easier.

Comment: @Everiste Server side ASP MVC is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload a file to SharePoint from C# code, the best is to use the [client-side C# API of SharePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx#BasicOps_SPCSOMOps). This only requires to add two DLLs as references to your Web app project (`Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll`).

Examples of usage to upload files:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9849835/3439544
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/965/programmatically-upload-document-using-client-object-model-i.aspx
- [how to upload file to sharepoint doc library via c# application?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45261/how-to-upload-file-to-sharepoint-doc-library-via-c-application)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22101266/3439544